# PowerShell Commands Will Not Respond Or Throws Error Using subprocess.run() in PyQt5

Tags: python, powershell, pyqt5

For two days now I have been trying to open the Control Panel Mail (Microsoft Outlook) Control Panel Item using Python `subprocess.run()` in a PyQt5 application.

I have narrowed it down to the two commands below:

```
 1.) `control mlcfg32.cpl`

 2.) `Show-ControlPanelItem *Mail (Microsoft Outlook)`
```

In PowerShell, command 1.) does nothing, no error, no anything. Command 2.) works fine. The Mail Setup applet open right up.

However, when trying to open the Main Setup applet in the PyQt5 application, I am not getting the same result. I have tried the two lines below:

```
 1.) `subprocess.run(["Powersehll.exe", "Show-ControlPanelItem", "*Mail (Microsoft Outlook)"], shell=True)`

 2.) `subprocess.run(["Powershell.exe", "control", "mlcfg32.cpl"], shell=True)`
```

Command 1.) gives the following error message:

```
Microsoft : The term 'Microsoft' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:30
+ Show-ControlPanelItem *Mail (Microsoft Outlook)
+                              ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Command 2.) does not open the Mail Setup applet, nor does it throw an error. It does absolutely nothing.

In File Explorer, I located the MLCFG32.CPL file and it does its job, opening the Mail Setup applet when the file is Double-clicked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl99y.jpg)

In addition to the commands listed above, I have also tried,

```
 - `subprocess.run(["PowerShell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy", "unrestricted", "Show-ControlPanelItem", "*Mail (Microsoft Outlook)"], shell=True)`
```

From the PyQt5 application, nothing has worked. I just have a button that's a dud. Could someone please help me with this problem?

The code in its entirety is shown below:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import subprocess
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Open Control Panel Mail (Microsoft Outlook) Applet")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES I/Cube.png"))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FFFFFF;")
        self.resize(450, 80)
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        self.widgets()
        self.center_window()
        self.show()

    def widgets(self):
        mail_btn = QPushButton("Mail (Microsoft Outlook)", self)
        mail_btn.setStyleSheet("font-size: 12pt; background-color: #B4D6FE;")
        mail_btn.move(140, 25)
        mail_btn.clicked.connect(self.open_mail_applet)

    def open_mail_applet(self):
        subprocess.run(["Powershell.exe", "Show-ControlPanelItem", "*Mail (Microsoft Outlook)"], shell=True)
        # subprocess.run(["Powershell.exe", "control", "mlcfg32.cpl"], shell=True)

    def center_window(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())


def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do just `Show-ControlPanelItem -Name mail*`

Comment: In addition, the reason for that error is the item name needs to be quoted because of the space, so: `subprocess.run(["Powershell.exe", "Show-ControlPanelItem", "-Name 'Mail (Microsoft Outlook)'"], shell=True)`. Also, `powershell.exe` was misspelled

Comment: Thank you Doug and Cpt.Whale. That was the solution. May I ask you which resources you use for PowerShell? I had issues with several other commands but was able to find solutions searching and reading on the web, but none of them spoke about formatting the commands in the subprocess.run(). If you have any suggestions I would appreciate it greatly. Thanks again.